# (SessionNotCreatedException) session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting the below exception despite of no webdriver version was changed and nothing was changed in project:

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[main]  01:29.743   FAILED      
                   Open error
                : (SessionNotCreatedException) session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
                : Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
                : System info: host: 'ILYA', ip: '172.31.210.211', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
                : Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumWebDriver
                : remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00F99563+2725219]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00E98551+1672529]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D80359+525145]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D10B77+68471]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D0D32C+54060]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D2CC37+183351]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D2CA3D+182845]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D2A94B+174411]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D12528+75048]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D135A0+79264]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D13539+79161]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00EAD607+1758727]
                :   GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6546+1050150]
                :   GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6291+1049457]
                :   GetHandleVerifier [0x010C10D7+1094071]
                :   GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6B46+1051686]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00EA5B06+1727238]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00EAEB7B+1764219]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00EAECE3+1764579]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00EC4C05+1854469]
                :   BaseThreadInitThunk [0x748F8494+36]
                :   RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E41C8+136]
                :   RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E4198+88]
                : (SessionNotCreatedException) session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
                : Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
                : System info: host: 'ILYA', ip: '172.31.210.211', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
                : Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumWebDriver
                : remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00F99563+2725219]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00E98551+1672529]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D80359+525145]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D10B77+68471]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D0D32C+54060]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D2CC37+183351]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D2CA3D+182845]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D2A94B+174411]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D12528+75048]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D135A0+79264]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00D13539+79161]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00EAD607+1758727]
                :   GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6546+1050150]
                :   GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6291+1049457]
                :   GetHandleVerifier [0x010C10D7+1094071]
                :   GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6B46+1051686]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00EA5B06+1727238]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00EAEB7B+1764219]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00EAECE3+1764579]
                :   Ordinal0 [0x00EC4C05+1854469]
                :   BaseThreadInitThunk [0x748F8494+36]
                :   RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E41C8+136]
                :   RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E4198+88]
TEST FAILED:
STEP FAILED:    Open error
MESSAGE:    (SessionNotCreatedException) session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83      
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'        
System info: host: 'ILYA', ip: '172.31.210.211', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'      
Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumWebDriver      
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:       
    Ordinal0 [0x00F99563+2725219]       
    Ordinal0 [0x00E98551+1672529]       
    Ordinal0 [0x00D80359+525145]        
    Ordinal0 [0x00D10B77+68471]     
    Ordinal0 [0x00D0D32C+54060]     
    Ordinal0 [0x00D2CC37+183351]        
    Ordinal0 [0x00D2CA3D+182845]        
    Ordinal0 [0x00D2A94B+174411]        
    Ordinal0 [0x00D12528+75048]     
    Ordinal0 [0x00D135A0+79264]     
    Ordinal0 [0x00D13539+79161]     
    Ordinal0 [0x00EAD607+1758727]       
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6546+1050150]      
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6291+1049457]      
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010C10D7+1094071]      
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6B46+1051686]      
    Ordinal0 [0x00EA5B06+1727238]       
    Ordinal0 [0x00EAEB7B+1764219]       
    Ordinal0 [0x00EAECE3+1764579]       
    Ordinal0 [0x00EC4C05+1854469]       
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x748F8494+36]     
    RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E41C8+136]      
    RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E4198+88]

        (SessionNotCreatedException) session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
        Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
        System info: host: 'ILYA', ip: '172.31.210.211', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
        Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumWebDriver
        remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
            Ordinal0 [0x00F99563+2725219]
            Ordinal0 [0x00E98551+1672529]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D80359+525145]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D10B77+68471]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D0D32C+54060]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D2CC37+183351]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D2CA3D+182845]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D2A94B+174411]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D12528+75048]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D135A0+79264]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D13539+79161]
            Ordinal0 [0x00EAD607+1758727]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6546+1050150]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6291+1049457]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x010C10D7+1094071]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6B46+1051686]
            Ordinal0 [0x00EA5B06+1727238]
            Ordinal0 [0x00EAEB7B+1764219]
            Ordinal0 [0x00EAECE3+1764579]
            Ordinal0 [0x00EC4C05+1854469]
            BaseThreadInitThunk [0x748F8494+36]
            RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E41C8+136]
            RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E4198+88]


        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:147)
        at kernel.core.selenium.drivers.SeleniumWebDriver.connect(SeleniumWebDriver.java:1484)
        at kernel.core.selenium.drivers.SeleniumWebDriver.open(SeleniumWebDriver.java:1252)
        at kernel.core.selenium.SeleniumWrapper.open(SeleniumWrapper.java:2190)
        at kernel.core.selenium.engine.EngineEntryPoint.operateStruct(EngineEntryPoint.java:162)
        at kernel.core.selenium.engine.EngineEntryPoint.open(EngineEntryPoint.java:142)
        at kernel.core.selenium.SeleniumWrapper.openWithClear(SeleniumWrapper.java:2894)
        at common.CommonApp.open(CommonApp.java:92)
        at common.CommonApp.open(CommonApp.java:86)
        at common.CommonApp.open(CommonApp.java:80)
        at web.beats.failures.FailuresA.preconditions(FailuresA.java:21)

STEP FAILED:    Open error
MESSAGE:    (SessionNotCreatedException) session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83      
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'        
System info: host: 'ILYA', ip: '172.31.210.211', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'      
Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumWebDriver      
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:       
    Ordinal0 [0x00F99563+2725219]       
    Ordinal0 [0x00E98551+1672529]       
    Ordinal0 [0x00D80359+525145]        
    Ordinal0 [0x00D10B77+68471]     
    Ordinal0 [0x00D0D32C+54060]     
    Ordinal0 [0x00D2CC37+183351]        
    Ordinal0 [0x00D2CA3D+182845]        
    Ordinal0 [0x00D2A94B+174411]        
    Ordinal0 [0x00D12528+75048]     
    Ordinal0 [0x00D135A0+79264]     
    Ordinal0 [0x00D13539+79161]     
    Ordinal0 [0x00EAD607+1758727]       
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6546+1050150]      
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6291+1049457]      
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010C10D7+1094071]      
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6B46+1051686]      
    Ordinal0 [0x00EA5B06+1727238]       
    Ordinal0 [0x00EAEB7B+1764219]       
    Ordinal0 [0x00EAECE3+1764579]       
    Ordinal0 [0x00EC4C05+1854469]       
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x748F8494+36]     
    RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E41C8+136]      
    RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E4198+88]

        (SessionNotCreatedException) session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
        Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
        System info: host: 'ILYA', ip: '172.31.210.211', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
        Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumWebDriver
        remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
            Ordinal0 [0x00F99563+2725219]
            Ordinal0 [0x00E98551+1672529]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D80359+525145]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D10B77+68471]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D0D32C+54060]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D2CC37+183351]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D2CA3D+182845]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D2A94B+174411]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D12528+75048]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D135A0+79264]
            Ordinal0 [0x00D13539+79161]
            Ordinal0 [0x00EAD607+1758727]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6546+1050150]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6291+1049457]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x010C10D7+1094071]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x010B6B46+1051686]
            Ordinal0 [0x00EA5B06+1727238]
            Ordinal0 [0x00EAEB7B+1764219]
            Ordinal0 [0x00EAECE3+1764579]
            Ordinal0 [0x00EC4C05+1854469]
            BaseThreadInitThunk [0x748F8494+36]
            RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E41C8+136]
            RtlAreBitsSet [0x779E4198+88]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was because the Chrome was in the middle of its automated update. Chromedriver was already updated to fit chrome v 83, while Chrome itself was still v81.